# Laravel 8 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages when running composer require laravel/passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

There are a lot of versions of this question floating around, but i haven't found any that deal with these specific packages.

I am trying to install laravel passport version 10 into my laravel 8 installation,
When running `composer require laravel/passport` i get the following response:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/passport[v10.0.1, ..., 10.x-dev] require illuminate/auth ^8.2 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport v10.0.0 requires illuminate/auth ^8.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, 10.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

found illuminate/auth ^8.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] <- I dont understand this part, does it have anything to do with having "minimum-stability": "dev" in my composer.json?

Anyways, here is my composer.json:

```
   {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.1",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5|dev-develop",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:
I tried running `composer require --no-update laravel/passport` and when i run `composer update` I get the following error(i though it may provide extra info):

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/passport[v10.0.1, ..., 10.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^8.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.2.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - laravel/passport v10.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[dev-master]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus 
cannot coexist with it.
    - laravel/framework 9.x-dev is an alias of laravel/framework dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[9.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, 10.x-dev].
```

EDIT 2:
To further explain the answer below, you have to delete the vendor folder and composer.json file inside your project, the you run `composer install` to downgrade to laravel 8.
After that you can run `composer require laravel/passport` and it will install properly

Comment: `"laravel/framework": "^9.0",` ? 9?

Comment: Good question, i haven't edited the composer.json, i don't know how that happened, do i change it to 8?, will it break anything?
EDIT: i changed and i got an extra error, so yeah it must be on a dev version:
`Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.0, found laravel/framework[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 9.x-dev (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Downgrade your Laravel version from 9 to 8

```
   {
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.1",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5|dev-develop",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: I tried downgrading by just switching the version in composer.json to 8.0, but i get the following error


```Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.0, found laravel/framework[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 9.x-dev (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.```


In my composer.lock it says this: 
                `"laravel/framework": "^8.0",`

Comment: To downgrade you also have to delete your vendor folder and your composer.lock file, then run composer install.

Comment: @javier1zq Thank you, I was struggling with this myself. Your comment about the folder and lock file removal is essential part of this answer!

Answer (score 24):

Just simple do one thing

remove **composer.lock** file and then install your required package

It work for me...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem just by modifying the `PHP PATH` on my operating system, at the time I am using `windows` with `WampServer`.

The change suggested above may work, but if a `composer install` command is being run, it is because an App already exists and is just downloading its dependencies, so changing the file suggested above can cause problems in the operation of the Application.
I think that changing the `PATH` note to the correct PHP version will work, in my case:
`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21` worked.

Valew.

Answer (score 0):

I vas trying to install `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` when I got this error. It required PHP 7.3+ and Laravel 8.0+ as described [here](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper?utm_source=pocket_mylist), but I had lower versions. So here are the steps I followed:

1. Deleted `composer.lock` file
2. Changed the version of PHP and Laravel in `composer.json`
3. Ran `composer install` which creates a new *composer.lock* file
4. Then ran `composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` and it was installed successfully